# Upgrade of docker gitlab image to 8.6 breaks gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab

After  gitlab docker image update to version 8.6:
`docker-compose pull`
`docker-compose up -d`

gitlab returned `http 500`

It seems that gitlab docker image 8.6 is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution:

`docker exec -it gitlab_web_1 /bin/bash`

`sudo -u gitlab-psql -i bash`

`/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql --port 5432 -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql -d gitlabhq_production`

`gitlabhq_production=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;`

`gitlabhq_production=# SELECT true AS enabled
FROM pg_available_extensions
WHERE name = 'pg_trgm'
AND installed_version IS NOT NULL;`

`\---------
 t
(1 row)`
`exit`

Database migration:

`gitlab-rake db:migrate`

Restart docker container:

`docker-compose stop;docker-compose up -d`

Hit refresh in browser.